# Angular 2 Router - change just named outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-auxiliary-routes

I have a primary router outlet and a named outlet.  The primary outlet contains a child router outlet.  When I try to change *just* the named outlet, it fails - I get routed to the default primary route and nothing happens in the named outlet.

AppRouter (primary/AppModule):

```
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: 'person/:id', component: PersonProfileComponent }
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Child Router (separate module) :

```
{
        path: 'person/:id',
        component: PersonProfileComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'people', component: PersonPeopleComponent }, 
            {
                path:'person-edit',
                component: PersonEditPanelComponent,
                outlet:'taskPane'
            },
}
```

From the PersonPeopleComponent (url of `#/person/8/people` - which matches `person/:id` in the primary outlet and `people` in the child outlet), I have the following RouterLink:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets:{taskPane : ['person-edit']} }]">Click Me!</a>
```

where `taskPane` is the named outlet.

What I would expect to happen is that the `PersonEditPanelComponent` would show in the `taskPane` named outlet, and the `PersonProfileComponent` and the `PersonPeopleComponent` would remain unchanged in the primary and child outlets.  Instead, what I see is the `Dashboard` route (my fallback route) gets loaded into the primary outlet and the `taskPane` outlet is empty.  No error is recorded in the console.

The href on my link ends up as something like `#/person/8/(people//taskPane:person-edit)` which doesn't work  (I've tried many different permutations on the router link so that is an example of just one invalid URL).  The URL needs to be `#/person/8/people(taskPane:person-edit)` which does work (I tested it manually) but I can't figure out how to set the RouterLink to generate that URL.

I **think** that the routes are configured correctly because the URL works when I hardcode it, which means then that the problem is in the RouterLink.

Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it.  Adding an empty string for the relative part of the routerLink worked:

`<a [routerLink]="['', {outlets: {taskPane: 'person-edit'} }]">Click Me!</a>`

```
                  ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Path for the primary outlet has to be set in `[routerLink]` directive. It's pretty easy to do with `Router` injected into the component:

```
@Component({
  template: `<a [routerLink]="[router.url, {outlets: {taskPane: ['person-edit']} }]">Click Me!</a>`
})
export class YourComponent {
  constructor(public router: Router) {}
}
```

If it still does not work, then I'd try to pass parameter for named outlet as a string in:

```
{outlets: {taskPane: 'person-edit'}}
```

Comment: OK, let me dig out the code and try it...thanks.  I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: This is getting closer.  Both of these options result in an href of **#/person/8/people/(taskPane:person-edit)** which still doesn't work.  The correct URL is **#/person/8/people(taskPane:person-edit)**.  The problem is the slash between the end of router.url **#/person/8/people** and **(taskPane:person-edit)**.  The slash isn't in either part, so it is definitely being injected by Angular somewhere, but I can't figure out how to stop it.

Comment: I solved it (see my answer).  I can't claim my own bounty and would rather not see it go to waste, so I'll give it to you since you were the only one who chimed in.  Thanks for the effort.